# implementing TTThumbsViewController on a UIViewController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

Im trying to implement add `TTThumbsViewController` as a subview of `UIViewController` but the app is crashing. Here you see the code-

.h file-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Three20/Three20.h>
#import <Three20UI/UIViewAdditions.h>
#import "MockPhotoSource.h"

@interface photos : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate, TTThumbsViewControllerDelegate>
{
    TTThumbsViewController *photoSource;
...........
}
```

.m File-

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

// parsing a feed
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:@"http://feed203.photobucket.com/albums/aa15/vikysaran/Worst%20Parents/feed.rss"];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];                         

    for (int i=0; i < [stories count];i++) {

        [arr addObject:[[[MockPhoto alloc] initWithURL:[[stories objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"fullimageurl"] smallURL:[[stories objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"thumburl"]
 size:CGSizeMake(960, 1280)] autorelease]];
    }
    photoSource = [[[MockPhotoSource alloc] initWithType:MockPhotoSourceNormal title:nil photos:[NSArray arrayWithArray:arr] photos2:nil]autorelease];
// till here the code is working fine if i am not using uiviewcontroller
        NSLog(@"mockphoto%@", arr);

        [self.view addSubview:photoSource.view];// adding to uiview
    }
```

here is the error displays-

```
-[MockPhotoSource view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6924ca0
2011-09-22 13:07:07.375 JesonTerry[1969:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MockPhotoSource view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6924ca0'
```

Please anybody help. i am totally confused where i am wrong...

Answer (score 1):

your view controller has to be a type `TTThumbsViewController` and not a `UIViewControler` for starters.. Check the TTCatalog app in the samples folder

Comment: i dont think so, is it not possible to inherit TTThumbsViewControllerDelegate to UIViewController?